# Display max value from two Div Tags

Tags: javascript, html, max, calculator

I use a math logic calculation plugin to calculate and seek the max result amount. After I input a value into the fields for calculation, the two divs below turn the total results, for example, 10 & 11.

```
<div id="value1">10</div>
<div id="value2">11</div>
```

If there's no input value for calculation, the two divs will display zero. What I want to do is I want to have the third div to display the max value from the two divs above. Is it possible to do with JavaScript or any other languages? Could you please suggest how to achieve that? I have searched on the internet but not found any information. It seems uncommon to find on the net.

Comment: Use ``document.getElementById("value1").innerText;`` and ``document.getElementById("value2").innerText;`` to get the content from the ``div`` and then you can use the values accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ?

```js
const value1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value1").innerText, 10);
const value2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("value2").innerText, 10);
document.getElementById("value3").innerHTML = Math.max(value1, value2);
```

```html
<div id="value1">10</div>
<div id="value2">11</div
<div>Value 3 : <span id="value3"></span></div>
```

And if you want a more generic code that work with N values :

```js
const values = [].map.call(document.querySelectorAll('.value'), function(div) {
  return parseInt(div.innerText);
});
document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = Math.max(...values);
```

```html
<div id="value1" class="value">10</div>
<div id="value2" class="value">30</div>
<div id="value3" class="value">20</div>
Result: <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This is exactly what I want to achieve. But I couldn't get it done since the divs comes from a shortcode. It works if I add raw html into a WordPress page. I've tried to adjust the JavaScript code based on those real divs (inspect elements from Chrome) accordingly but I get an error" TypeError: Cannot read property 'innerText' of null
 /form/:1281"

Comment: That's another problem ; if the divs are dynamically generated, maybe they're not in the DOM when you execute this snippet

Comment: Ok, I'll ask the plugin author, thank you.